# Export to excel, Column header display error in ColdFusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion, export, cfml

I am trying to get account numbers by a query and displaying those account numbers as column header after exporting into excel.

The following code is working fine but displaying wrongly:

```
<cfset variables.setHeader = "">
<cfoutput query="myLoop"> 
    <cfset variables.setHeader = variables.setHeader & ", C_#myLoop.acc#> 
</cfoutput>
```

The above code is displaying column header (just one sample data I am showing here) but it is showing as 'C_000391'. Which is wrong! For display, 'C_' should not be with account number, it is the account number which should create the column header alone. However, as soon as I am taking off 'C_' from infront of #myLoop.acc# it is giving the following error:

```
The column name 000391 is invalid.
```

Please let me know what will be the best solution(s) to resolve this toughest problem on earth :)

Thanks

Comment: The `C_` is correct as that is what your loop is stating.  My guess is that the column names HAVE to be string and 000391 will be looked as as numeric unless you do something like quote it to make sure that it is seen as text

Comment: The code above would not produce that error. You need to post the code that is *causing* the error, as well as the *full* error message.

Comment: *Re: it is showing as 'C_000391' Which is wrong!* Why? All I can tell from the above is that the code is concatenating the string `"C_"` with what appears to be an account number from a query ie `#myLoop.acc#`. So the results are exactly what I would have expected. What did you expect to happen instead .. and why?

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are trying a form a comma separated list , try below , no looping required.

< cfset variables.setHeader = ValueList(myLoop.acc) >